# If $_POST gives empty value make it 0

Tags: php, html, forms, post, html-post

```
$message .= "First name = ".$_POST['first-name']."\n";
$message .= "Last name = ".$_POST['last-name']."\n";
$message .= "Address line = ".$_POST['address-line']."\n";
$message .= "City = ".$_POST['city']."\n";
$message .= "State = ".$_POST['state']."\n";
$message .= "Country = ".$_POST['country']."\n";
$message .= "Postal code = ".$_POST['postal-code']."\n";
```

So let's say I submited a form that didnt inculde the first name input

then the result will show up like

```
First name = 
Last name = something
Address line = something
City = something
State = something
Country = something
Postal code = something
```

the first name was left empty

now my question is how can I change this so if a $_POST value was empty give 0

to make the result show up like this

```
First name = 0
Last name = something
Address line = something
City = something
State = something
Country = something
Postal code = something
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to sanitize posted values and return a default value:

```php
function getPost($key) {
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $_POST))
    return 0; // $_POST[$key] is not defined
    
    return stripslashes(trim($_POST[$key]))?:0; // 0 if empty after cleaning
}
```

Then use like below:

```php
$message .= "First name = ".getPost('first-name')."\n";
$message .= "Last name = ".getPost('last-name')."\n";
// ... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if (!isset($_POST['first-name']) || $_POST['first-name']==''){
    $_POST['first-name'] = 0;
}
```

Comment: how can I make this apply for every $_POST without  having to specify $_POST['first-name'] and $_POST['last-name'] etc

Comment: Excellent question - but that is another question. The best way to manage the new question is to close out this question (by choosing a preferred answer) and asking a new question. In the new question, you can reference this question (just add a link to the question URL) and after asking it you can put a comment below this one with the URL of the new question and I'll see that and be able to respond. *By adding your next question as a new question, hundreds of people will be able to see it and respond, while this one is now quite far down the list and only a handful will see your new query.*